# Accessing initialized variable on different class C++

Tags: c++, variables, class

I'm having some difficulties with this problem.

The main idea is, I initialized a variable of class type B in class A, class A.h has the variable Z declared as public, like B *Z;

In class A.cpp, I initialized it as Z = new B();

Now, I want to access that variable from class C and I'm unable to do so. C.h includes A.h and B.h

Here goes a bit of code:

Car.h

```
#include "Model.h"

class Car {
public:

    static Model *Z;

}
```

Car.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"

void Car::init() {
    Z = new Model();
}
```

Model.h

```
Class Model {}
```

Camera.h

```
#include "Model.h"
#include "Car.h"

class Camera {}
```

Camera.cpp

```
Camera::init() {
    Car::Z->getPos();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what issue you're having. Can you post actual code that isn't working?

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to access it. Do you get an error message?

Comment: I'm with Michael... hard to tell what is going on without the code. You may want to brush up on the c/c++ scope rules.

Comment: Ok... the answers are now getting weird... please tell us more! :S

Comment: Yup, Im getting this: 
error: object missing in reference to ‘MyApp::MyCar::model’

Comment: Well, I'll try to help out.
There are 3 classes, car, model and camera. in car I declare a new model Z and I want the camera to follow that model so I'll have to access the model positions in camera class

Comment: Dude, just paste your code.  We won't steal it, we promise =P

Comment: Car.h

#include "Model.h"

class Car {
public:

 static Model *Z;

}

Car.cpp

#include "Car.h"

void Car::init() {
 Z = new Model();
}

Model.h

Class Model {}

Camera.h

#include "Model.h"
#include "Car.h"

class Camera {}

Camera.cpp

Camera::init() {
 Car::Z->getPos();
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I initialized a variable of class type
>   B in class A

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

class A
{
   public:

   B* Z;
   A()
   { 
      Z = new B();
   }
}
```

> B.h

```
#pragma once
class B
{ 
}
```

> C.h

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

class C
{ 
   A a; //here you construct A
   C() 
   { 
      a.Z = new B(); //you can read/write Z
   }
}
```

This should work! Be careful to include the `#pragma once` or a header guard/include guard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file) so the headers won't be included twice (if should have done it).

> There are 3 classes, car, model and
>   camera. in car I declare a new model Z
>   and I want the camera to follow that
>   model so I'll have to access the model
>   positions in camera class

- A = Car
- B = Model
- C = Camera

Comment: #pragma once is not really standard, I believe it is not supported by for instance the intell c++ compiler (or a few versions ago).
 Include guards are the standard way of dealing with multiple inclusion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: so will'nt it be like when C is constructed,memory for object B will be allocated inside a(When Constructor of A is called) but after that,you are calling for new B inside the constructor of C and putting at z,So will'nt it lead to a memory leak?

Comment: @mawia: Yes... but that's not the point. I wanted only to show that you can access Z. And I didnt want to write a test method ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it a static variable? If not you have to access it from an instance of class A.

From what you wrote, it sounds like it's static though. In that case, in A.h you have to say

```
static B *Z;
```

Then in A.cpp, you have to define it:

```
B *A::Z;
```

Then in C.cpp, you can access it like

```
A::Z->whatever();
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting error when I try the 2nd step it says B is not a member of A

Comment: FWIW, defining it would be B* A::Z;

Comment: oops, I should have tried to compile it before posting :). B* A::Z; is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing something like this?

```
class A{
public:
    A() : m_B( new B() );
    B* getB() const { return m_B;}
private:
    B *m_B;
};

class C{
public:
    B* getB() const { return m_A.getB(); }
private:
    A m_A;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have

```
class A {  
public:  
    B* Z;  
};  

class B {  
public:  
    // Empty  
};  

class C {  
public:  
    // Empty  
};
```

So to say...there is no reason why you SHOULD be able to access Z. Your question ist not percice enough to say...but you should do

```
class C {
public: 
    A* z_access;
};
```

Now you can use "a" Z in class C by using class A.
But we need more information to see what is really going on.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated question:

Your problem is that you have not actually defined the `Car::Z` variable anywhere. You have a *declaration* for it in the `Car` class, but there is no definition anywhere.

What you need is to add, in the car.cpp file, the line:

```
Model* Car::Z;
```

Or, optionally, if you want to give `Z` an initial value, something like:

```
Model* Car::Z = NULL;
```

This is needed in general for static member variables that are anything other than constant integers. You need the declaration in the `class { }` block, and then you *also* need a definition in the corresponding .cpp file, otherwise you will get this error.